# How to find web project path from Eclipse in Java file?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I want to get the eclipse project path in java.i have one java file using  web project in eclipse.in that web project i created folder like splittedfiles.
so i want get this folder path..

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String p = path + "\\" + "splittedfiles\\";
System.out.println("path " + path);
System.out.println("file path " + p);
```

whenever i try to execute the above code in my java page its getting  software installed path only.
 i run this on apache tomcat server

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if I understood your question:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath();
```

SRC/ folder is compiled to BUILD/CLASSES/, so all you put in src/* goes to classes/*

which is the root of any java application at any IDE.

Ok for find folder under webcontent directory use following

```
  String a = this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath();
  System.out.println("a=> "+a.replaceAll("/build/classes/", "/splittedfiles"));
```

May be this will help..

i tried this also ...but it will show the same path

```
a=>/D:/Eclipse%20Running%20project/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MultiCloud_Architecture/WEB-INF/classes/
```

use this for updating the path you are looking for

```
  System.out.println("a=> "+a.replaceAll("/WEB-INF/classes/", "/splittedfiles"));
```

Comment: i tried this but get the classes folder in WEB-INF but i want like this.... i created a folder like splittedfiles under the WebContent in eclipse..now u want this folder path..

Comment: check the edit done in above answer for finding path of folder inside "WebContent" folder.

Comment: @Raju have you tried the solution you just need to do a replace on this path and get whatever path you need in the projects 'webcontent' folder.
Have you tried this?

Comment: now itself only i tried this..but its not working properly....i get this below path but it shows the error